# Removing items from a collection using WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a checked listbox in a Windows Forms app that allows the user to assign one or more security groups to a selected user.

Using WCF Data Services, I am able to populate the box without a problem.  However, as the user changes selections in the box and tries to save those changes, I run into issues.

Here is the code, with comments to explain my logic.

```
private void ProcessSecurityGroupSelection_Original()
{
  //Get a reference to the selected user, including the associated SecurityGroups.
  var user = _ctx.Users
    .AddQueryOption("$filter", "UserID eq " + ((DataService.User)lstUsers.SelectedItem).UserID)
    .AddQueryOption("$expand", "SecurityGroups")
    .First();

  //Remove all the SecurityGroups so we can replace them.
  user.SecurityGroups.Clear();

  foreach (var selectedGroup in lstSecurityGroups.CheckedItems)
  {
    //Loop through the selected SecurityGroups, linking and adding each SecurityGroup to the User object.
    var securityGroup = (from sg in _ctx.SecurityGroups
                 where sg.SecurityGroupID == ((DataService.SecurityGroup)selectedGroup).SecurityGroupID
                 select sg).First();

    _ctx.AddLink(user, "SecurityGroups", securityGroup);

    user.SecurityGroups.Add(securityGroup);
  }

  _ctx.UpdateObject(user);
  _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the code hits the AddLink method for a SecurityGroup that had previously been selected, I get an error stating "The context is already tracking the relationship." It doesn't appear that the Clear() method removes any links in the context.

How do I go about removing the existing links, or am I approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to remove the links is to add an event like the following:

```
private void lstSecurityGroups_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        _ctx.DetachLink(user, "SecurityGroups", securityGroup);
    }
    else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        _ctx.AddLink(user, "SecurityGroups", securityGroup);
    }
}
```

Note that `DeleteLink` will mark the entity for deletion also, which will cause an error if called multiple times. If you just want to remove the link, use `DetachLink`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Using the first option, assume my checked listbox has three items.  When my form loads the first one is checked, the others are not.  I can toggle the ones that are unchecked with no problems and save the state of each.  I can also clear the box that was originally checked and save without problems.  However, if I uncheck it and change my mind and check it again, I immediately get the same error.  It's as if the DeleteLink didn't actually delete the link.  Just a note that I used e.NewValue rather than e.CurrentValue.  I think that's what you intended in the code.

Comment: I like the looks of the second option better, but I don't know what you mean by DataServiceCollection<Category>.  Is there something I can read that will help me understand?  Thanks again.

Comment: Can you try the amended first option to see whether or not it works? I know how ugly it is. The second option is more relevant to people who are adding new links (rather than removing and adding). It could be made to work by doing a similar check for the LinkDescriptor.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me through this.  It appears the LinkDescriptor.State property is read-only.

Comment: Hmm... I was definitely able to set it on my end. Are you saying that because of the XML docs? (I thought the same thing initially, but was able to set it at runtime w/o a problem.) Also, which version of WCF DS Client are you using? I was on 5.0.1. As far as taking time, no worries whatsoever - I'm pretty new to the WCF DS team, so it helps me identify where the really ugly parts of our API are. :)

Comment: I was using 4.0 but this morning I upgraded to 5.0.0.0 and I'm still unable to assign to LinkDescriptor.State. I've narrowed the problem down a little. If I have no security groups selected and I choose one it works fine.  If I then deselect that same one it works fine.  But if I reselect it I will run into a problem when when I do the AddLink.  However, if I call _ctx.SaveChanges() after I DeleteLink and before AddLink it works without a problem.  But that leaves me in a spot where I can have inconsistent data, so I really don't want to take that approach.  What am I missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: Perhaps not related, but looking at the MSDN documentation, it seems like my SecurityGroup object should have a navigation property that will get me back to the related User.  The SecurityGroup has a Users collection, but it's always empty.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not able to repro the code I had before (though I did run it through the debugger several times; not really sure where the disconnect happened). At any rate, it looks like there's a substantial difference between deletelink and detachlink - delete propagates to the entity. Try replacing the call to deletelink with one to detachlink and see if things work properly. This gist works for me: https://gist.github.com/3083943.

Comment: I think the difference with the gist sample and my scenario is that I'm dealing with a many to many relationship.  I posted a better description of the issue on the WCF Data Services forum. Here's a link:  http://tinyurl.com/c7jjk9b

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a silverlight project. I have taken the solution which worked for me and applied it to your User/SecurityGroup model.

Add the following to your user class:

```
public User()
    {
    this.SecurityGroups.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
        if (e.Action == Add)
            {
            foreach (SecurityGroup AddedGroup in e.NewItems)
            AddSecurityGroup(AddedGroup);
            }
        if (e.Action == Remove)
            {
            foreach (SecurityGroup RemovedGroup in e.OldItems)
            RemoveSecurityGroup(RemovedGroup);
            }

        };

    ..... rest of constructor
    }



public void AddSecurityGroup(SecurityGroup secGroup)
    {
    LinkDescriptor descriptr = _ctx.GetLinkDescriptor(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);

    if (descriptr == null)
        _ctx.AddLink(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);

    else if (descriptr.State == EntityStates.Deleted)
        _ctx.DetachLink(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);

    }


public void RemoveSecurityGroup (SecurityGroup secGroup)
    {
    LinkDescriptor descriptr = _ctx.GetLinkDescriptor(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);

    if (descriptr == null)
        {
        _ctx.AttachLink(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);
        _ctx.DeleteLink(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);
        }

    else if (descriptr.State == EntityStates.Added)
        _ctx.DetachLink(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);

    else
        _ctx.DeleteLink(this, "SecurityGroups", secGroup);

    }
```

Now remove the line:

```
_ctx.AddLink(user, "SecurityGroups", securityGroup);
```

from your code above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on A Aiston's answer I prepared a set of extensions to help with handling of Added then Deleted and Deleted then Added links in general.

1. It's generic
2. AddSecurityGroup shoud also attach link if it was previously deleted
3. I prefer to avoid magic strings at some small performance cost

   ```
   public static class DataServiceContextExtensions
   {
       public static void AddOrAttachLink<TSource>(this DataServiceContext context, object source, Expression<Func<TSource>> sourceProperty, object target)
       {
           AddOrAttachLink(context, source, sourceProperty.GetExpressionMemberInfo().Name, target);
       }

       public static void AddOrAttachLink<TSource, TTarget>(this DataServiceContext context, TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> sourceProperty, TTarget target)
       {
           AddOrAttachLink(context, source, sourceProperty.GetExpressionMemberInfo().Name, target);
       }

       public static void AddOrAttachLink(this DataServiceContext context, object source, string propertyName, object target)
       {
           var descriptor = context.GetLinkDescriptor(source, propertyName, target);
           if(descriptor == null)
           {
               context.AddLink(source, propertyName, target);
           }
           else if(descriptor.State == EntityStates.Deleted)
           {
               context.DetachLink(source, propertyName, target);
               context.AttachLink(source, propertyName, target);
           }
       }

       public static void DeleteOrDetachLink<TSource>(this DataServiceContext context, object source, Expression<Func<TSource>> sourceProperty, object target)
       {
           DeleteOrDetachLink(context, source, sourceProperty.GetExpressionMemberInfo().Name, target);
       }

       public static void DeleteOrDetachLink<TSource, TTarget>(this DataServiceContext context, TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> sourceProperty, TTarget target)
       {
           DeleteOrDetachLink(context, source, sourceProperty.GetExpressionMemberInfo().Name, target);
       }

       public static void DeleteOrDetachLink(this DataServiceContext context, object source, string propertyName, object target)
       {
           var descriptor = context.GetLinkDescriptor(source, propertyName, target);
           if(descriptor == null)
           {
               context.AttachLink(source, propertyName, target);
               context.DeleteLink(source, propertyName, target);
           }
           else if(descriptor.State == EntityStates.Added)
           {
               context.DetachLink(source, propertyName, target);
           }
           else
           {
               context.DeleteLink(source, propertyName, target);
           }
       }

       public static MemberInfo GetExpressionMemberInfo(this Expression expression)
       {
           var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expression;

           MemberExpression memberExpression;
           if(lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
           {
               var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
               memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
           }
           else
           {
               memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
           }

           return memberExpression.Member;
       }
   }
   ```

Usage:

```
var ctx = new YourContext();
ctx.AddOrAttachLink(addTo, () => addTo.Collection, toAdd);
ctx.DeleteOrDetachLink(removeFrom, () => removeFrom.Collection, toRemove);
```

Comment: Coming back to this question after so long reminds me of how much I dislike the way this technology obstructs sensible OOP. +1 for the generics.